# IE does not parse any JS after unsupported code?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I want to use certain JS code, but only according to whether the browser supports the @supports (CSS) and CSS.supports() (JS) properties/functions.

Now, Internet Explorer does not support CSS.supports() or @supports. This is fine - the idea is to build the JS code so that, if the browser doesn't support either of them, then it falls back to a working version.

This works flawlessly on all other browsers, even those which do not support @supports / CSS.supports().

But in IE, it parses the JS code all the way up to the first mention of CSS.supports(), and then it breaks entirely and does not parse a single character after that.

I'm working with IE 11, and here's the JS code I'm using (I'm also using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var port = $(window);
    var container = $('html, body');

    if( !CSS.supports("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") & CSS.supports("perspective", "1px")) {
        var port = $('.prllx');
        var container = $('.prllx');
    };

    // OTHER CODE GOES HERE
});
```

However, as I said, IE does not read ANY code after the IF check.

I then tried to make a test code, to see what happens with a more simple example:

```
    var helloworld = !CSS.supports("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch");
    $("#test").html(helloworld);            
    if (helloworld == true) {
        $("#test2").html("HELLO WORLD FROM WITHIN IF");         
    };
```

But IE doesn't parse ANYTHING after the first line (I've been inserting         $("#div").html("HELLO WORLD"); lines every other line to see at which point IE stops parsing JS, and it literally happens right after the first mention of CSS.supports.

I can't seem to get my head around this: In all other browsers which do not support CSS.supports(), the IF (in my first example) obviously fires false, and the variables remain unchanged. But they continue to parse the remaining code after that instance, even if they don't/can't parse CSS.supports() because they don't support the function. But IE stops parsing entirely.

I have to say that I am not particularly fluent with javascript, so I might be missing something really simple here - or it might actually be a bug, in which case, how do I go around it? How can I check whether the browser supports CSS.supports() without breaking the entire code in case it is IE?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any browser that doesn't have a `CSS` object with a `supports` property that refers to a function will throw an exception where indicated below:

```
$(function() {
    var port = $(window);
    var container = $('html, body');

    // vv Exception on this line
    if( !CSS.supports("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") & CSS.supports("perspective", "1px")) {
        var port = $('.prllx');
        var container = $('.prllx');
    };

    // OTHER CODE GOES HERE
});
```

When an unhandled exception is thrown in a function, control is tranferred out of the function, and no code following the place where the exception occurred will run. This is not an IE thing, it's how JavaScript and most other languages with exceptions work.

Instead, put in a guard checking whether `CSS` exists and if so whether it has a `supports` that's a function:

```
$(function() {
    var port = $(window);
    var container = $('html, body');

    if( typeof CSS === "object" &&
        typeof CSS.supports === "function" &&
        !CSS.supports("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") &&
        CSS.supports("perspective", "1px")) {
        var port = $('.prllx');
        var container = $('.prllx');
    }

    // OTHER CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Some host-provided functions report `typeof` incorrectly. In that case, you may need to change the `=== "function"` above to `!== "undefined"`. That's a weaker guard, because not everything that's not undefined is callable, but sometimes host-provided functions don't report `"function"` as they should.

---

Side note: The logical "and" operator in JavaScript is `&&` (as above), not `&`. The `&` is the *bitwise* "and" operator (coerces its operands to 32-bit integer numbers and combines them at the bit level). It matters primarily because `&&` *short-circuits*, which means that if its left-hand operand is falsy (for instance, `typeof CSS === "object"` is not true), it doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand **at all**, so we can safely do something assuming the left-hand operand is truthy (such as looking at `CSS`'s `support` property).

Side note 2: You don't put a `;` after the end of the block attached to a control-flow statement. It's harmless, but pointless.

Comment: This now did not work on latest version of Chrome (MacOSX).

I reversed the typeof check to  !== "undefined" like so:

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise ENTER posts my message - was just starting to edit my response again:

Thanks a ton! This worked:

`if ( typeof CSS !== "undefined" && typeof CSS.supports !== "undefined" )`

This now it works on all previous browsers and does not break on IE.

Your solution didn't fire up any errors in my Chrome console, but the variables weren't changed as expected.

Changing it to !== undefined worked very well, though. Perhaps the typeof CSS !== "undefined" is unnecessary, and only 'typeof CSS.supports !== undefined" would be enough?

Comment: @Laonikoss: Ah, okay. Yes, there would be a small chance of `typeof CSS.supports !== "undefined"` not being sufficient defense (because you're going to call it, and not everything that's not undefined is callable), but some host-provided objects and functions do report the wrong `typeof` (the most common error is `"object"` for a host-provided function). I've folded that into the above.

Comment: Right - but given that it works on sufficiently well for this particular function, would it be worth adding extra OR parameters in the IF (or nesting them) to check for all the possible `typeof`, or would `!== "undefined"` suffice?

Comment: @Laonikoss: If it were me, I'd probably call `!== "undefined"` good enough. :-)

Comment: Great, thanks! And I appreciated your other comments too (about the `;` for example). I've only picked up JS from reusing bits and bobs from different places, so I'm not very familiar with proper syntax! :)